# windows scroll using javascript in fluid layout. How?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys [check this page](http://www.girisoft.net/louisa/). This page has fluid layout now. I applied width:100%; min-width:800px and max-wdth:1280px. Now if the user resize/shrink the page i want both vertical and horizontal scroll bar. I applied overflow:scroll; but its not working. Is there any javascript available there to enable this feature? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect scrollbars, if you have an `overflow: hidden;` on the body-tag? If I delete this, both scrollbars appear.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that inline styling.

Answer (score 2):

You applied overflow:scroll where?....there is an inline style of `overflow: hidden;` added t the body tag in the html, remove that and you will get your scrollbars back.